# Wordpress Admin Page Post Status Menu Item Doesn't Show Count Label or Bold When Active

Tags: php, wordpress

hopefully I explained that properly. In essence, I created an additional menu item in the Posts admin page in Wordpress. It filters results using the category I created perfectly. The issue is that I'm missing what makes the menu item display the post_count label and become bold to show it as the active link like the other status menu items do (All (4)| Published (3)| Private (1) etc.). In this case, Projects is the menu item I created.

Here is the code I've got thus far and a screenshot of what I'm talking about.

```
add_action( 'views_edit-post', 'remove_edit_post_views' );
function remove_edit_post_views( $views ) {
    $views['pre'] = '<a class="'.$class.'" href="'.admin_url().'edit.php?category_name=project">Projects <span 
class="count"></span></a>';
    return $views;
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'special_list');

function special_list( $q ) {
  require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/screen.php');
  $scr = get_current_screen();
  if ( is_admin() && ( $scr->base === 'edit' ) && $q->is_main_query() ) {
  if ( $scr->category_name !== 'project' ) return;
    $pre = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pre', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if ( $pre === 'pre' ) {
      $meta_query = array( 'key' => 'is_special', 'value' => 'yes', );
      $q->set( 'meta_query', array($meta_query) );
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bold you need to add `current` class. I updated some of your code. check below code.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'special_list' );
function special_list( $wp_query ) {
    if( is_admin()) {
        add_filter('views_edit-post', 'remove_edit_post_views');
    }
}

// add filter
function remove_edit_post_views($views) {
    global $wp_query;
    
    $my_cat = 'project';

    $query = array(
        'post_type'   => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'cat'         => $my_cat
    );
    $result = new WP_Query($query);
    
    $class = ($wp_query->query_vars['category_name'] == 'project') ? ' class="current"' : '';
    $views['project'] = sprintf(
                            __('<a href="%s"'. $class .'>Project <span class="count">(%d)</span></a>', 'project'),
                            admin_url('edit.php?post_type=post&category_name='.$my_cat),
                            $result->found_posts
                        );

    return $views;
}
```

Tested and works

[image]

Comment: It did! Although now the count is off. It seems to be showing the count for published rather than only posts with the desired category.

Comment: I will back to you.

Comment: I think you need to debug a little bit. because it's work for me.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what the deal is. I enabled debugging but don't see any errors being thrown. It works perfectly except the count is counting every published post, rather than only counting posts with the desired category.